# How to check if a procedure in many databases is the same?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

The situation is that we are having a SQL instance with many databases on it. Most of the databases have a specific procedure.

Is there a way to check with SQL if the body of this procedure is the same in all databases?

I want to do this, because sometimes I need to make a "mass deploy" on some procedures, functions or views, but in this case I am not sure if the procedure has not been modified after its creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases
```

will give you a list of your databases. You could load the database names into a cursor and loop over each of your databases. Next,

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION, * 
FROM DatabaseName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
```

will give you a list of your stored procedures. You may need to use dynamic SQL to dynamically set the DatabaseName part coming from your cursor. The ROUTINE_DEFINITION column will contain the stored procedure body. You can then compare this column to see if it is the same or different with your other databases and etc.

Answer (score 0):

the following t-sql will give you the definitions of existing stored procedure. From here you may try to test if the definitions are what they should be

```
select 
    o.name, m.definition 
from 
    sys.objects o
    left join sys.sql_modules m on o.object_id = m.object_id 
where o.type = 'P'
```

a more complete sample:

```
set nocount on
declare @spName nvarchar(100) = 'usp'
declare @spDef nvarchar(max) = 'create procedure ....'
declare @spDefInDb nvarchar(max)
declare @nstSql as nvarchar(max)

declare @tdbs table (
    dbName nvarchar(50),
    done bit
)

insert into @tdbs select name, 0 from sys.databases

declare @currentDb nvarchar(50) = null
select @currentDb = dbName from @tdbs where done = 0

while (@currentDb is not null) begin
    --print @currentDb
    set @nstSql = N'select @spDefOut = m.definition from ['+@currentDb+'].sys.objects o left join ['+@currentDb+'].sys.sql_modules m on o.object_id = m.object_id where o.name=@spNameIn and o.type = ''P'''    
    set @spDefInDb = ''
    exec sp_executesql 
        @nstSql,
        N'@spDefOut nvarchar(max) output, @spNameIn nvarchar(100)',
        @spDefOut = @spDefInDb output, @spNameIn = @spName

    if ( @spDefInDb is not null and @spDefInDb != '' ) begin
        print @currentDb
        print @spDefInDb
    end

    update @tdbs set done = 1 where dbName = @currentDb
    set @currentDb = null
    select @currentDb = dbName from @tdbs where done = 0
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar once:  using the T-SQL CHECKSUM function, I calculated a checksum for the body each stored procedure in each database, and stored the procedure name and the checksum in a table.   It's pretty easy, then, to construct a query comparing these tables between two databases:   If constructed using Dynamic SQL, you could build a automatic query that compares the procedures in each database against a reference database   (I did this for a company that provided ACH functions for a number of banks, and wanted to maintain parallel databases for security reasons).

If you want specific guidance on building the function, leave a comment, and I'll try to oblige.

Answer (score -1):

something like this? 
note that I'm making use of undocumented and unsupported `Sp_MSForEachDB`

USE [SomeDatabase]

```
CREATE TABLE spdef(
    dbname sysname, 
    sptext NVARCHAR(MAX))

EXEC Sp_MSForEachDB 'use ?; INSERT INTO [SomeDatabase]..spdef(dbname, sptext) SELECT '' + ? + '', OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(N''VerifyPortalTab''));'
```

Then you can do the comparisons between databases offline

* Edit ***
Following @AaronBertrand recommendation I don't want to promote this answer

Comment: Please [stay away from `sp_msforeachdb` for several reasons](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25311/differential-backup-successfully-completes-without-taking-the-backup-of-few-data/25313#25313).

Comment: @AaronBertrand thank you. I used it very sporadically for quick and dirty stuff. Never had such a problem as you showed, but I'll take it consideration from now on. nb: I mentioned that is `undocumented`

Comment: Right, but just saying "undocumented" without any disclaimers makes it sound (at least to me) like it's an ok secret and part of the cool kids' club. This is why I always say undocumented *and unsupported*.

Comment: gotcha. I'll try to remember in my future responses. 1+ for your constructive remarks!

Comment: @LuisLL That's pretty simple and clean, but I am getting results or definitions for database where the procedure should not exists - like the "master" - do you have any ideas what is causing that?

Comment: @gotqn, thank you for trying it, but as this conversation, Aaron Bertrand recommends not using this. As for your problem probably you are getting the error since you are not part of SYSAdmin role and the server is denying access, I would be possible to solve it with try/catch, but I would recommend you discard this answer.

Comment: @LuisLL Actually, I have checked too the AaronBertrand reference - it's a shame that the sp_msforeachdb function is not documented and fixed.

Comment: @gotqn +1, Sp_MSForEachDB is(was) quite useful.